# Using LEN() function on non-character based languages

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to use LEN() to measure text strings that can be in various languages. The idea would be to use it as a constraint for comments that are under a certain length.

I'm running into an issue where if the language is not English, len() is not calculating a length.

Is there anyway around this? Is there some other function that can be used to figure out how long a string is?

Comment: DataLength will include trailing spaces. What is an an example of string with incorrect len?

Comment: len() will work with different language, should not be an issue. something else will be problem

Comment: Can you define what a "non-character based language" might be?

Comment: For example, if the comment is Thai, and WHERE LEN(Table1.[Comment]) >= 60 it's saying there is not comment larger than 60 characters. Which there are some very lengthy comments.

Comment: Are you using `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: `LEN` won't work with `TEXT` and `NTEXT` columns. But that should give you an error... For those column types you'll need to use `DATALENGTH`.

Comment: To @DavidFaber comment, see the following article on using LEN with unicode data types. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic431183-8-1.aspx

Comment: It's not throwing any errors. Len() works just fine for English, Spanish, French, German, etc. It's only when I try to run it on Thai, Urdu, Greek it's not calculating the length. @MicSim I'll read up on datalength.

Comment: Please post a sample that len() is not correct.

Comment: If I try to do a 
SELECT 
   T1.PersonID
FROM 
   TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN
   TABLE2 T2
ON 
   T1.PersonID = T2.PersonID
WHERE
   LEN(T2.COMMENT) >= 60

Then no PersonID is returned for a Thai string that is 100+ characters in length

Example of String:
นี่คือการทดสอบ ฟังก์ชั่น ความยาว เมื่อ มีมากกว่า หกสิบ ตัวอักษร ในสายที่ไม่ได้รับ การบันทึกโดย ฟังก์ชั่น ความยาว

Comment: `LEN()` works OK for Greek, whether you use Unicode or not. It's not a multi-byte codepage (if that's what you mean by "non-character based"). Are you sure your join returns any data with comments larger than 60 characters? Please post the SQL statements needed to reproduce the error, including code that actually creates and populates the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returns the correct answer for me

```
select 'len gt 60' 
where len('นี่คือการทดสอบ ฟังก์ชั่น ความยาว เมื่อ มีมากกว่า หกสิบ ตัวอักษร ในสายที่ไม่ได้รับ การบันทึกโดย ฟังก์ชั่น ความยาว') >= 60
```